# L'Hospital's rule for $g(x)\to\infty$ only

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim_{x\to a^+}g(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)}$ exists, then $$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)}.$$

I am aware of that there is a proof of this in Rudin's analysis book.  However I'm looking for a proof that is easier to understand.  Or alternatively a slight rewrite of Rudin's version which explain why there exists points $c_1, c_2$ etc etc, for those who have access to that.

Comment: What is Rudin's proof? Not everyone own the book...

Comment: Try rearranging $\frac{f(x)} {g(x)} $ to $\frac{\frac{1} {g(x)} }{\frac{1} {f(x)}} $ and applying L'Hopital's rule...

Comment: @Holo there is a link to text here: https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf , the proof is given on pg 118/119 of that PDF.

Comment: I find the proof in Wikipedia easier to digest. Do have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof

Comment: @ShreyanshDarshan: that would require $f(x) \to \infty $ also.

Answer (score 1):

Existence of $c_1$:

$g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to a^+$ means (by definition) that for any $M$ there is an interval $(a,c_1)$ where $g(x)>M$. Apply this with $M=\max(g(y),0)$.

Existence of $c_2$:

Formula (20) has the form $f(x)/g(x) < h(x)$ for $x \in (a,c_1)$, where $h(x) \to r-0+0 = r$ as $x \to a^+$. And $r<q$, so there is an interval $(a,c_2)$ where $h(x) < q$. (Apply the definition of $h(x)\to r$, with $\varepsilon = q-r$.) And we can decrease $c_2$, if needed, to make $(a,c_2) \subset (a,c_1)$.
Then $f(x)/g(x) < h(x) < q$ in $(a,c_2)$.